# map through array of objects Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to fetch some data which is array of objects. I want to extract one field from these objects and I'm using `Array.map()` for that, but argument for the method is any(because I didn't specify the type) and I can't access any fields of the object. The thing is, I could use interface or type to construct the object type I get but the objects in the array have many fields and are nested. So is there another, simpler way to solve this problem?
Here's the code:

```
async function getData() {
      const res= await axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/Curiosity/photos?earth_date=2016-5-4&camera=MAST&api_key=DEMO_KEY')
      const photos=res.data.photos.map(elem=>elem.img_src)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is, I could use interface or type to construct the object type I get but the objects in the array have many fields and are nested.

This is the beauty of interfaces though. You don't necessarily need to write up the full type, but only the properties you are interested in. Just because you don't give type information to the full response object and all of it's complex nested values, it doesn't mean that the service won't return those at runtime.

Based on `res.data.photos.map(photo => photo.img_src)`, It looks like the shape of the data you are interested in would be a `data` property, which contains a `photos` property, which is an array of complex objects that you map through in order to grab the `img_src` property.

So I would write up two interfaces, one for the response, and the other for the property of the photo object:

```
interface IResponse {
    data: {
        photos: IPhoto[];
    }
}
```

```
interface IPhoto {
    img_src: string;
}
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUAWB7M3kDeAUMqcsALYDmA%20gM5QIBcydYUoVA3EQL5FFQkWIhSoAShDoAHbCDopiZZABM4YOCyXKy0nHjosM%207AG0Auj2X9%20RAPR3kAWWwIA1sgCCAD2DY6yHAgKsgQwbJCyFBSsvIQRAhybIG%20-sgAvIQkZFQQYCwwAK4gCGB%20IMgAPAAqkjIZgSAAngA0yNWeUFQNQU0AfAAUAHQjcF2G7Z1UFgCUWTpk0WCFUBUgEADuyOhQ2BTACjV10oNQGX2sedWUENiFYAMDc%20kX2gvKUAMEquqahMh6XD%20Fimb6UWgMZjIADkKwANgBGaHIXhtMHUeiMFiwqBwgBMyN45hRJLgAV6Mys71RyDxAAY6TNKdlSDYBGSmiVkEUSmU5MhcmAACK-J7zMiJeRgKJSHobODAaVwVJ0IaCyoSGJJCBtNgcEBUQbQzBgMDSQwOODSYBDEBkuBq7AANzsFDGdAAtICDHYrcA7E6EXZdk7oHQ7ABhFZ%20OiKpp2b3%20AD8EDGYEwNDUkHS9IRADYPQBWD0AFgAZAg4BRoHB0k5PABlaplv00NwQJrpIUAUScAHkaABpbsATWhMxZyElyUTAUy0VVWYds6GbukA0T5wBJiG4MxCAnymn2DhECGcOwVA3JjozL4REFIo0TyAA)

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I assumed I had to write the entire type of an object, otherwise I would get an error. Now I know specifying the fields I'm interested in is just fine and that's great.